# Ranged attack in Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have two objects: a player and an enemy. The main problem is the enemy, which should start shooting at the player when it approaches him at a certain distance (in short, just start the animation).
At first I tried to implement this through Vector 3, as with other ordinary opponents. But he is as stupid and crutch as possible, however, you yourself can see everything in the pinned.

I started to implement it more allegedly correctly, through the trigger and the collider (box collider) of the enemy itself. And everything works right as it should, but there is a nuance. The enemy also has boxing implemented through the box collider, the player, hitting which, causes damage to him. There is only one box collider for these two tasks, and since I had to increase this collider so that the enemy could stop in front of the player at a certain distance. Because of this, the player can hit at a great distance (at which the enemy can shoot) from the enemy and the enemy takes damage anyway.

I tried to make a separate object the size of the enemy himself and use it as a box to receive damage. Then he already transmits data about receiving damage to the enemy object. But this does not work, all links between scripts and objects are made, but he does not want to transfer data. That is, simply making two colliders for different tasks does not work.
In general, here my powers are all. I searched the entire Internet, but I did not find how to implement this mechanic in a different way so that it does not conflict with others. Therefore, I ask the help of the local experts, where I screwed up.

```
private Animator ch_animator;
// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    myAgent = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
    myAnim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    EnemyH = GetComponent<GDHealth>();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    dist = Vector3.Distance(/*checker.*/transform.position, target.transform.position);
    if (dist > range)
    {
        myAgent.enabled = false;
        myAnim.SetBool("Idle", true);
        myAnim.SetBool("Move", false);
        myAnim.SetBool("Attack", false);
    }
    if (dist <= range & dist > atRange)
    {
        myAgent.enabled = true;
        myAgent.SetDestination(target.position);
        myAnim.SetBool("Idle", false);
        myAnim.SetBool("Move", true);
        myAnim.SetBool("Attack", false);
    }
    if (dist <= atRange)
    {
        StartCoroutine(Attack());
    }
    if (PlayerH._health <= 0)
    {
        atRange = 0;
    }
    if (EnemyH._health < 0)
    {
        myAgent.enabled = false;
    }
}

public IEnumerator Attack()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f);
    myAgent.enabled = false;
    myAnim.SetBool("Idle", false);
    myAnim.SetBool("Move", false);
    myAnim.SetBool("Attack", true);
}

void OnTriggerStay(Collider col)
{
    if (col.tag == "Player")
    {
        //gameObject.GetComponent<Animator>().SetBool("Attack", true);
        StartCoroutine(Attack());
        transform.LookAt(col.transform.position);
        transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, transform.eulerAngles.y, 0);
    }
}
void OnTriggerExit(Collider col)
{
    if (col.tag == "Player")
    {
        myAgent.enabled = true;
        myAgent.SetDestination(target.position);
        myAnim.SetBool("Idle", false);
        myAnim.SetBool("Move", true);
        myAnim.SetBool("Attack", false);
        //gameObject.GetComponent<Animator>().SetBool("Attack", false);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please use the correct tags! Note that [`[unityscript]`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a custom JavaScript flavor-like language used in early Unity versions and is **long deprecated** by now. Your code is of course in `c#`

Answer (score 0):

> But this does not work, all links between scripts and objects are made, but he does not want to transfer data.

From this description it could be anything: wrong layers, no rigidbody on either of objects, misstyped tags in `OnTriggerStay` method.

In my project, I successfully created 2 colliders for 2 separate tasks, so this is how I would see it in your problem:

1. Use two colliders

Attach one collider with one script to the enemy object - this collider should have a size of the enemy. The `OnTriggerStay` method here should deal damage to the enemy, check for death, etc.
Create child object to the enemy. Attach **new** collider to it with the size of enemy's attack range. Attach a script with `OnTriggerStay` method that will stop enemy and begin ranged attack (or whatever you want to do).

If this doesn't work: check collision matrix or try adding a kinematic rigidbody to either of objects.

2. Measure distance between player and the enemy in update (which you are already doing) and apply necessary code based on distance (stop or attack) thus replacing one of the colliders.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Yes, I did exactly as you described. The problem is that the unity doesn't want to pass data from one object to another. I created a collider for the enemy to take damage and created a child object with a collider called TargetBoxSU, which is responsible for the attack distance. I created a separate script for the Targetox, which simply sent to another script that is attached to the enemy, took methods from that script and executed them when the TargetBox was triggered. But no matter how I make the link, unity does not see it.

Comment: What do you mean by unity doesn't want to pass data? Between which objects do you want send data, and what is that data? Maybe you have a problem with referencing one object to another?